# Cloud Functions for Firebase - Error on Deploy

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a function which listens to the notifications tree and then sends a push notification to the user.

However  keep getting this error (seen below), I have other functions which are working and cannot seem to debug this.

Thanks.

```
Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers.

exports.sendFollowerNotification = functions.database.ref(‘/user_notifications/{userId}/{notificationId}’).onWrite(event => {
                                         ^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:16:9)
```

And this is my code function code:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions'),
  admin = require('firebase-admin'),
  logging = require('@google-cloud/logging')();

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendFollowerNotification = functions.database.ref(‘/user_notifications/{userId}/{notificationId}’).onWrite(event => {

const userId = event.params.userId;
const notificationId = event.params.notificationId;

const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database().ref(`/users/${userId}’).once('value');

const getNotificationPromise = admin.database().ref(‘/notifications/${notificationId}’).once('value');

return Promise.all([getDeviceTokensPromise, getNotificationPromise]).then(results => {

    const userSnapshot = results[0];
    const notification = results[1];

if (!userSnapshot.hasChildren()) {

        return console.log('There is no user to send to.');

    }

const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: ‘Covet Notification!’,
            body: `${notification.description}`,
        sound: 'default',
                badge: '1'
         }
 };

const token = userSnapshot.pushToken

return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)

}); 

});
```

Comment: You're missing a `require` statement for the `functions` library: `var functions = require('firebase-functions');`

Comment: Sorry that was my bad, I forgot to put it in this question and have edited accordingly now. Thanks.

Comment: There are also some weird back-quotes in there that seem improperly nested/paired. E.g. `\`/users/${userId}’`